# Hanging 100 pound mirror on cement wall

Tags: concrete

How do I hang a 100 pound mirror on a cement wall?  Special hooks?  Thank you.

Comment: Are we talking cement *block*, or a poured concrete wall?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is/are the proper method and tools for drilling into masonry?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/33485/what-is-are-the-proper-method-and-tools-for-drilling-into-masonry)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use masonry anchors.  This thread will give you the info you need.

[What is/are the proper method and tools for drilling into masonry?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/33485/what-is-are-the-proper-method-and-tools-for-drilling-into-masonry)