# Fasten 1/4" steel plate to 2x4 wood?

Tags: wood, screws, fence, steel

I have several 2"x4" x 12ft pieces of wood that I will use as rails. I need to secure them to several 1/4" steel plates. The steel plates have two holes for screws ( or whatever I end up using). The wood doesn't have holes and I don't want the screw to go completely through the wood.

What's the best way to secure the 2x4 to these plates?

Thanks.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're asking. What specifically is the problem you face? With no idea what you're building, what can we say?

Comment: Yes we need more details and possibly some design drawings.

Answer (score 1):

> **The wood doesn't have holes**

So I'd use something like a bradawl to mark the positions then drill a pilot hole if necessary (depends on wood, position of hole, diameter of screw etc)

See [How can I drill to an exact depth with a hand drill?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/31705/2815)

> **and I don't want the screw to go completely through the wood.**

That's just a matter of buying the right sized screw.